# Detect number of fingers on the scrollview before touch goes into content view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I am already visiting array of `UIGestureRecognizer` in the scrollview and make `maximumNumberOfTouches` to be `2` to allow both one/two finger swipe/drag gesture for my custom scrollview. 
The thing I want to do is to identify between when it's a one finger drag and when it's a two finger drag. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method **-(NSUInteger)numberOfTouches** of UIGestureRecognizer could tell you how many touches on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    int count = [[event allTouches] count]; // this should be 1 or 2
}
```

Comment: are you sure you can get touchBegan called in a uiscrollview? It's deprecated.

Comment: I just tried this and it works - and I'm not seeing any deprecation warning for it.

Comment: May I ask where do you add touchesBegan methods to, in the scrollview subclass or in the content view?

Comment: @overboming: I'm not sure where your content view is relative to the scrollview, but I think you want to add the touchesBegan etc. methods to your scrollview subclass (I put the method in a subclass of UIScrollView myself, to make sure it's not deprecated).

Comment: Weird, how come my - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event never get called in UIScrollView, touchesCanceled is called when I start dragging.

Comment: If there's something else (like, another view) on top of your UIScrollView, it will pick up the touches instead of the scroll view (although I don't know why `touchesCancelled` would make it through). Sorry, I'm too new to iPhone to figure this out - maybe you can post your code?